# cooling/refrigeration essentiality for carbonated softdrinks

Tags: thermodynamics, food-chemistry

How does cooling/refrigeration help in maintaining the taste and shelf life of food products, especially CSD (Carbonated Soft Drinks)? For example, chilled drinks have a nicer taste than a normal drink and may have longer shelf life. Why is that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q10_%28temperature_coefficient%29), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility#Solubility_of_gases) and possibly [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelf_life#Temperature_control). Then come back and specify your question a little more, as it is too broad at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. I incorporated info from your comment into the question and cleaned it up a little. This question may still be too broad.

Comment: reasons for the cooling/refrigeration is to -ensure that the carbonic acid in the drink hasn't all decomposed (=no bubbles). Keeping it cold slows down the bacteria reproduction (=longer shelf life) and as for the nicer taste - it tastes more fresh when its cooled

Answer (score 0):

It has a longer shelf life because the bacteria, (which is the reason it will go bad), cannot reproduce as fast in cold temperatures.

As far as taste goes with carbonated soft-drinks, I think it is mostly just about preference.

Comment: Sodium benzoate (which is in a lot of drinks), or other preservatives, prevent bacteria growth, so the drinks don't need to be chilled.

Answer (score -2):

Refrigeration condenses the CO2 and allows for a "softer" bubble feel in the mouth.  

As for shelf life of soda, it should not effect a "canned" soda one way or another.